# STL list container class of programmer defined Classes

Tags: c++, list, stl

I'm having trouble accessing member functions of classes stored in an STL `list`. My code is below:

```
typedef Shape* shapePtr;
list <shapePtr> shapeList;    

//skip alot...

    case x: 
            {
                cout << "Enter the height \n";
                cin >> height;
                cout << "Enter the base \n";
                cin >> base;

                //computation.
                shapeList.push_back(new Triangle);
                shapeList->setHeight(height);
                shapeList->setBase(base);
                break;
             }
```

This resulted in the following error with g++:

> operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type
>
> error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*shapeList’

```
     case x:
            {
                cout << "Enter the height \n";
                cin >> height;
                cout << "Enter the base \n";
                cin >> base;

                //computation.
                shapeList.push_back(new Triangle);
                (*shapeList).setHeight(height);
                (*shapeList).setBase(base);
                break;
            }
```

Resulted in the following error:

> error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*shapeList’

Answer (score 3):

`shapeList` refers to the list as a whole.  If you want the last element of the list, use `shapeList.back()`, which returns a reference to the last element (a `shapePtr&` in this case).

However, since it looks like you're calling methods that are specific to `Triangle` instances (which I assume is a subclass of `Shape`), so you can't interact directly with `shapeList.back()` because a `Shape` doesn't have those methods.  What you need to do is separate out the allocation of a `Triangle` instance from adding it to `shapeList`.  Allocate the `Triangle` and store it in a local variable.  You can then add it to that list, and call `setHeight` and `setBase` on it via that local variable.

Comment: Thanks, the project instructions say that I have to only use base class pointers, but I'm going to do as you suggest, as it is the only way that I see making sense. Thank you very much

Comment: If `Shape` has the two methods virtual then the code is fine as is. Just work with the pointer inside the container, not the container holding the pointer.

Comment: Thanks wilhelmtell, how would I work with the pointer in this case?

Comment: As @AdamRosenfield suggested: `Shape *s = shapeList.back();` this will give you the last pointer you `push_back()` ed. Then you can work with the pointer: `s->setHeight(height);`. Of course, if you constructed the triangle polymorphically to begin with then you don't need to extract it from the container. You already have it in your hand because you just constructed it!